# Finishing a sub-function with setTimeout loop before function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I've been wrestling with a timing issue in my code for a few nights now, and can't come up with the correct solution.

Psuedo code description:

//event listener on button trigger a die roll each time it is clicked

// call animation function
   //generate random values x number of times
   //display each result with setTimeout
 //run code to determine final "settled upon" value and display results

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Make Cards</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Total:<span id="total"></span></p>
  <div id="contain">

  <div class="die"></div>
  <div class="die"></div>
  <div class="die"></div>
  <div class="die"></div>
  <div class="die"></div>
  <div class="die"></div>

    <br>

  <button id="rollBtn">Roll</button>
  <input type="number" value = "1" min="1" max="6" id = "numDice">

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var diceValue = ["&#9856", "&#9857", "&#9858", "&#9859", "&#9860", 
"&#9861"];
var dice = document.querySelectorAll(".die");
// select number of dice
var numDice = document.querySelector("#numDice");
// convert string to value
var newNumDice = Number(numDice.value);
var roll = document.querySelector("#rollBtn");
var total = document.querySelector("#total");


// make animation function
// call animation function


init();

function init(){
  displayDice();
  }
//THIS IS THE BUTTON LISTERNER
roll.addEventListener("click", function(){
//THIS SHOULD RUN BEFORE THE REST OF THE FUNCTION (BUT DOESN'T SEEM TO)
  animate();
  var subTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < newNumDice; i++){
    var value = generateRandomDice() 
    dice[i].innerHTML = diceValue[value];
    subTotal = subTotal + (value+1);
    total.innerHTML = subTotal;
  }      
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    dice[i].style.color = "black";
  }
                      })


numDice.addEventListener("click", function(){
  total.innerHTML = "-";
   newNumDice = Number(numDice.value);
  resetDice();
  displayDice();
  // console.log(Number(numDice.value));
})

function resetDice(){
  for (var i = 0; i < diceValue.length; i++){
    dice[i].innerHTML = "";
  }
}

// only display chosen number of dice

function displayDice(){
  for (var i = 0; i < newNumDice; i++){
    dice[i].innerHTML = diceValue[i];
  }
}

function generateRandomDice(){
  var dieSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  return dieSide;
}

//ATTEMPT AT WRITING CODE FOR ANIMATION
function animate(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
  var ani = setTimeout(rolling, 650);
  }
  }

function rolling(){
                for (var i = 0; i < newNumDice; i++){
    var value = generateRandomDice() 
    dice[i].innerHTML = diceValue[value];
    dice[i].style.color = "grey";
}
}
```

Not sure what is going on, but it appears to me that the animate(); code is not run until the rest of eventListener is finished. Any help is great, thank you.

Comment: What's not working?  I ran your codepen, and it looks like it's doing what you want.

Comment: The original code was out of sync. I will delete my comment because it has been fixed with the help of the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are waiting for asynchronous code to finish before you execute synchronous code. Every time you call setTimeout, it is storing the function to call for when it's ready to be called (which is 650 ms from 'now'!).

To fix, you can `await` for your animation to finish. Here's how I got it working on your codepen:

Change `animate` to:

```
function animate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        rolling();

        if(i == 49999)
          resolve();
      }, 650);
    }
  });
}
```

and then you can await for the Promise to resolve by changing your click listener to this:

```
roll.addEventListener("click", async function() {
  await animate();
  var subTotal = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < newNumDice; i++) {
    var value = generateRandomDice();
    dice[i].innerHTML = diceValue[value];
    subTotal = subTotal + (value + 1);
    total.innerHTML = subTotal;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    dice[i].style.color = "black";
  }
});
```

The result showing afterward was correct for me.

Hope that helps!

Comment: `Promise` is getting to be pretty well supported, and can be polyfilled if needed (e.g. for IE11 support). `async/await` is es2017, so much more recent addition than `Promise`. Most of the evergreen browsers have decent support, but if you need older browser support this can't be polyfilled. You'd have to transpile the code to use it. If this is an issue you can use the `Promise.then().catch()` syntax. Or you could (shudder) use a callback if you don't want to have to worry about polyfilling.

Comment: Well, first let me say thanks for fixing my code. This does indeed fix it as you suggest. I was aware of promise, but not await, which seems to be the real fix in terms of timing. I don't think I entirely understand all of this yet but that will be my homework for later. Now I have to go about fixing things so that 6 dice don't take 6 times longer to roll then one.